# Behaviour of Coefficient[] for negative exponents in rational expressions

Tags: functions, coefficients

I've observed a puzzling behaviour of `Coefficient[]` for negative exponents and I'm wondering if I was always just relying on undefined behaviour or if there is a bug in recent versions of Mathematica.

So far, if I had an expression of the form

```
expr = a/x + b/(1+x) + c
```

and ran

```
Coefficient[expr,x,-1]
```

I've always gotten

```
a
```

as the answer, which made a lot of sense to me.
I've tried this with a number of different versions of Mathematica (all on Linux if that matters) that I had access to and the behaviour described above is true for 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.4, 9.0.0, 9.0.1, 10.0.0, 10.0.1, 10.4.0, 10.4.1, 11.0.0 and 11.0.1.

With 11.1.0, 11.1.1, 11.3.0 and 12.0.0 I got the answer

```
a + b/(1+x)
```

which I find a bit weird, but maybe I can come up with a rationale behind this.

Finally, with 12.1.1 and 12.2.0 I get

```
a/(1+x) + b/(1+x) + c/(1+x)
```

which makes absolutely no sense at all to me.

My question is: Is this a bug in the newer versions of Mathematica or was the answer of 8.0.0 to 11.0.1 always just undefined behaviour? And is there a workaround, which would allow me to extract the coefficient `a` from expressions like the one above (i.e. after partial fractioning a rational function, take only the term that is multiplied by `x^k` with `k` a negative integer)? If this is indeed undefined behaviour, shouldn't Mathematica issue a warning or something like that in this case?

Comment: I think MMA does not consider a Laurent series to be a polynomial. At least  the help does not mention any negative exponents. However, you could determine the smallest negative exponent and multiply the Laurent series with the corresponding power of x to transform it into a polynomial that MMA  can digest.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report it (among other reasons, so I don't forget to have a look at it).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've now reproduced this behaviour also with Mathematica 12.2.0 (question edited accordingly). I'll write to Wolfram to report this as a potential bug. If there are any updates, I'll try to add the information also here.

Comment: Please do report the TS tracking number. I will want to follow up in-house.

Comment: TS tracking no longer needed; I received the bug report. Thanks for raising the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @DanielHuber said in the comment, since `PolynomialQ[a/x + b/(1 + x) + c, x]` gives `False`, and [`Coefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient.html) is claimed to work for polynomials:

> `Coefficient[expr,form]`
>
> - gives the coefficient of *`form`* in the **polynomial** *`expr`*.
>
> `Coefficient[expr,form,n]`
>
> - gives the coefficient of *`form`*^*`n`* in *`expr`*.

It may thus be an undefined behavior for non-polynomials. As a workaround you can define that:

```
coefficient[expr_, form_, n_Integer : 1] := 
 Total@Cases[expr, e_ /; FreeQ[e/(form^n), x] :> e/(form^n)]
```

so that in v*12.2*

- `coefficient[expr, x, -1]` gives `a`
- `coefficient[expr, 1 + x, -1]` gives `b`
- `coefficient[expr, x, 0]` gives `c`
- `coefficient[a/x + b x/(1 + x) + c, x, 0]` gives `c`
- `coefficient[Apart[a/x + b x/(1 + x) + c], x, 0]` gives `b + c` since $\frac{x}{1+x}=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$